# Raspberry Pi Connected to a Pixma IP2770 printer not actually printing

Tags: printing

I successfully installed the Cups, follow the steps in the tutorial in the internet with out any problem   Then when it supposed to print a document the power of the printer blink ( meaning the printer detected) but the printer not procceed and not printing the document.. What should I do to make the printer actually printing docu.?

Comment: Have you tried to print the test page?

Comment: Yes, I already try but still not working.

Comment: What tutorial do you follow? Please edit the question and add a link.

Comment: It's already okay, I can print using rpi.. By the way, thank you.

Comment: Please make an answer with a short explanation. It will finish the question and show others that it has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried every tutorial I search online.. because if one doesn't work try another..  don't give up coding..  I don't know the specific solution just happen that when I tried printing it work successfully..